# How to map model class with api response Angular 5

Tags: angular, model, mapping

I have a api response :

```
{
 "response_type": 1,
 "msg": "",
 "success": true,
 "status": 200,
 "data": {
   "first_name": "Divyashree M",
   "user_id": 258031,
   "svc_id": 2,
   "svc_name": "21North India",
   "address": {
    "country": "india",
    "street_name": "queens road",
    "locality": "not defined",
    "door_number": "0",
    "zipcode": "pipoi--"},
   "logo_url": "url",
   "permission_type_id": 1,
   "is_admin": 0,
   "company_type": 1,
   "designation_id": 1,
   "term_status": 0
 }
}
```

interface which i created is :

```
interface RootObject {
  response_type: number;
  msg: string;
  success: boolean;
  status: number;
  data: Data;
}

interface Data {
  first_name: string;
  user_id: number;
  svc_id: number;
  svc_name: string;
  address: Address;
  logo_url: string;
  permission_type_id: number;
  is_admin: number;
  company_type: number;
  designation_id: number;
  term_status: number;
}

interface Address {
  country: string;
  street_name: string;
  locality: string;
  door_number: string;
  zipcode: string;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to map json with model class and also how to check whether the correct data type is coming from api or not with all the properties of the class . I tried using map function from Rxjs but i got stuck.Please help me.

Comment: @kaiu/serializer is a serializer designed to do exactly this, documentation available on https://kaiu-lab.github.io/serializer/

Answer (score 0):

We need to know a bit more to help you. How do you call your API? Is it an observable?

I see that the API response and the interface have the same structure.
Try adding a constructor to each of your model like this :

```
    export class RootObject {

      constructor(obj: any) {
         _.assignin(this, obj);
      }

      response_type: number;
      msg: string;
      success: boolean;
      status: number;
      data: Data;
    }

    export class Data {

      constructor(obj: any) {
         _.assignin(this, obj);
      }

      first_name: string;
      user_id: number;
      svc_id: number;
      svc_name: string;
      address: Address;
      logo_url: string;
      permission_type_id: number;
      is_admin: number;
      company_type: number;
      designation_id: number;
      term_status: number;
    }

export class Address {

      constructor(obj: any) {
         _.assignin(this, obj);
      }

      country: string;
      street_name: string;
      locality: string;
      door_number: string;
      zipcode: string;
    }
```

If your getting your API response via HTTP, it should be something like that :

```
let rootObject: RootObject;
this.http.get(url, options).subscribe(data => rootObject = new RootObject(data));
```

Comment: I am using websocket :

Comment: it is an observable please help me in this.

Comment: I already have, if you want further explanations then tell us more about your code and environnement.

Comment: Hi, this is how I am sending data to backend:                                      
 OnSubmit({ value, valid }: { value: Ilogin, valid: boolean }) {
    var obj = {
      app_id: 1,
      request_type: 1,
      method_type: 1,
      mobile: value.mobile,
      password: value.password
    }
    console.log(this.chatService.messages); 
    this.chatService.messages.next(obj); 
}

Comment: How to validate data type coming from backend.